# How to set env for custom symfony bootstrap

Tags: php, symfony, codeception

I use Codeception for acceptance tests. However as I need to prepopulate database with necessary entities, I need symfony kernel. I created a TestKernel:

```
class TestKernel extends KernelTestCase
{
    public static function boot(): ContainerInterface
    {
        $_ENV['KERNEL_CLASS'] = 'App\Kernel';
        $_ENV['APP_ENV'] = 'test';
        putenv('APP_ENV=test');
        require_once codecept_root_dir('config/bootstrap.php');
        static::bootKernel();
        return static::$container;
    }
}
```

Here I extend from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase` as it is used in phpunit tests. I also require `config/bootstrap.php` as `phpunit.xml` does. And I try to set test env but it does not work for now. I tried `$_SERVER, $_ENV, putenv` but all of them give the same result: `.env.dev` is loaded instead of `.env.test`. Can not get a clue. When run `APP_ENV=test ./vendor/bin/codecept run` test env is used. I thought I should be able to set env in php. Anyway phpunit does it somehow.

**Edit**
I see that I caused some confusion. Let me show how I use `TestKernel`:

```
class PageCest {
    public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $this->container = TestKernel::boot();
        $this->fixture->setContainer($this->container)->createProducts();
        $I->amOnPage('/my-page');
    }
}
```

As you see I create a completely separate symfony instance in acceptance test (I see no other way).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. In **acceptance** tests, your server should already be running. This is the command which launch your server that determines the environment. Are you speaking about acceptance tests or functional tests? (*Personnaly, I'm using KernelTestCase with unit test to test my repositories.*)

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant I updated the Q. It is acceptance test. I just used `KernelTestCase` as it has all necessary things to boot a kernel.

Comment: Thanks for update. I understand. Nice tips! I'm searching a solution...

Answer (score 1):

The issue relates to Codeception. The problem was that Codeception loads `.env` files by its own. There is the key `params` in `codeception.yml`:

```
params:
    - .env
```

Which loads env files. From the first glance it does what symfony does - loads `.env` file and that loads all derived files according to `APP_ENV` value: if `APP_ENV` is dev - it loads `.env.dev`. But Codeception uses a different logic - it loads only file it does not load environments files. In this case it loads only params from `.env` and not `.env.dev`.

To make it clear, both Symfony and Codeception use the same packages for env file loader: `symfony/dotenv`. While Symfony uses `#loadEnv`, Codeception uses '#load`. And this explains the difference I am talking about.

Taking all this into consideration the solution was quite simple: add new item to `params` key - '.env.test`. In this case my`TestKernel` will look like:

```
class TestKernel extends KernelTestCase
{
    public static function boot(): ContainerInterface
    {
        $_ENV['KERNEL_CLASS'] = 'App\Kernel';
        static::bootKernel();
        return static::$container;
    }
}
```

And `codeception.yml`:

```
params:
    - .env
    - .env.test
```